# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ATL::CTraceCategory ATL::atlTraceException" (?atlTraceException@ATL@@3VCTraceCategory@1@A)

Tags: c++, parsing, mfc

I am trying to run this program on Visual Studio 2013, but when I include an object - myparser.obj I am getting the following error:

```
1>MyParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ATL::CTraceCategory ATL::atlTraceException" (?atlTraceException@ATL@@3VCTraceCategory@1@A)
1>MyParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class ATL::CTrace ATL::CTrace::s_trace" (?s_trace@CTrace@ATL@@2V12@A)
1>MyParser.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AtlTraceVA referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ATL::CTrace::TraceV(char const *,int,unsigned long,unsigned int,char const *,char *)const " (?TraceV@CTrace@ATL@@QBAXPBDHKI0PAD@Z)
```

Is there something wrong with the myparser or is it something else?

Code4A.h

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#define IDC_BUTTON 501
#define nInput 6

extern double parse(CString,int,double [],int []);

class CCode4A : public CFrameWnd
{
protected:
typedef struct
{
    CString label,item;
    CPoint hm;
    CEdit ed;
    CRect rc,display;
} INPUT;
INPUT input[nInput+1];
CStatic result;
CFont Arial80;
CButton btn;
int idc;
public:
CCode4A();
~CCode4A();
afx_msg void OnPaint(),OnButton();
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

class CMyWinApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};
```

Code4A.cpp

```
#include "Code4A.h"

CMyWinApp MyApplication;

BOOL CMyWinApp::InitInstance()
{
CCode4A* pFrame = new CCode4A;
m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
pFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
pFrame->UpdateWindow();
return TRUE;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCode4A,CFrameWnd)
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON,OnButton)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CCode4A::CCode4A()
{
Create(NULL,"Code4A: Scientific Calculator",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CRect(0,0,700,350),NULL);
Arial80.CreatePointFont(80,"Arial");
idc=301;
input[0].hm=CPoint(200,20);
for (int i=1;i<=nInput;i++)
    input[i].hm=CPoint(input[0].hm.x+10,input[0].hm.y+50+(i-1)*30);
input[1].label="t"; 
input[2].label="u"; 
input[3].label="v";
input[4].label="x";
input[5].label="y";
input[6].label="Expression";
btn.Create("Compute",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    CRect(CPoint(input[0].hm.x,input[0].hm.y+5),CSize(100,20)),
    this,IDC_BUTTON);
for (i=1;i<=nInput-1;i++)
    input[i].ed.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 
    CRect(input[i].hm.x+70,input[i].hm.y,input[i].hm.x+150,
    input[i].hm.y+20),this,idc++);
input[nInput].ed.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 
    CRect(input[nInput].hm.x+70,input[nInput].hm.y,
    input[nInput].hm.x+350,input[nInput].hm.y+20),this,idc++);
result.Create("",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER | WS_BORDER, 
        CRect(input[nInput].hm.x+50,input[nInput].hm.y+50,
        input[6].hm.x+150,input[6].hm.y+70),this,idc++);
}

CCode4A::~CCode4A()
{   
}

void CCode4A::OnPaint()
{
CPaintDC dc(this);
CString str;
dc.SelectObject(Arial80);
dc.SetBkColor(RGB(255,255,255));
dc.SetTextColor(RGB(100,100,100));
for (int i=1;i<=nInput;i++)
    dc.TextOut(input[i].hm.x,input[i].hm.y,input[i].label);
dc.TextOut(input[6].hm.x,input[6].hm.y+50,"Result");
}

void CCode4A::OnButton()
{
CString str;
int i,psi[nInput+1];
double z,psv[nInput+1];
for (i=1;i<=nInput;i++)
    input[i].ed.GetWindowText(input[i].item);
psi[1]=19; 
psi[2]=20; 
psi[3]=21; 
psi[4]=23; 
psi[5]=24;
for (i=1;i<=nInput;i++)
    psv[i]=atof(input[i].item);
z=parse(input[nInput].item,5,psv,psi);
str.Format("%lf",z);
result.SetWindowText(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## include "atlbase.h"

should fix the problem

Comment: I think it can use #pragma comment( lib, "libname.lib" )

Answer (score 1):

Check your project settings, you are missing linker input to atls.lib.

Set the project to /NODEFAULTLIB and explicitly link it to atls.lib

/[NODEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a.aspx)

Comment: it makes the errors multiply terribly ;/ the fault is with the parser, when I delete it and all code that uses it the problem dissapears.